# cuando intento hacer la inserción en la BD dentro del else no consigue el campo en la colección del mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
var consulta_user;
var userVar;
var passVar;
if (Meteor.isClient){
Template.regiter.events({
        'submit form': function(event, template){
            event.preventDefault();
            userVar = event.target.usuarios.value;
            passVar = event.target.passwd.value;
            consulta_user = Meteor.user.findOne({email:userVar});
        console.log(consulta_user);
        var evaluo = consulta_user.email;
        console.log(evaluo);
                if(userVar == evaluo){
                    alert("error");
                }else{
            Meteor.user.insert({
                        'email':userVar,
                        'password':passVar
                    });
                alert("EXITO"); 
                }//fin else `

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Por favor, cuando vayas a publicar código, que esté bien indentado (tabulado/sangrado). Es lo mínimo que deberías ofrecer si esperas que alguien les tu código. Además, ¿podrías agregar una pequeña descripción de tu problema, o de lo que hiciste hasta ahora para generar un poco de contexto, más allá de lo que escribiste en el título?

Answer (score 0):

En tu Template utilizas  los input, esta parte del codigo va en Client

```
 <Template name="mitemplate"
<input id="userVar " name="userVar " type="text" placeholder="Usuario">
<input id="passVar " name="passVar " type="password" placeholder="Password">
</Template>
```

En tu Helper

```
Template.mitemplate.events
        ({
          'submit form': function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var userVar =event.target.userVar .value;
            var passVar =event.target.passVar .value;
                 Meteor.call('AgregarUsuario',userVar,passVar ,function(error,result)
            {
              if(error){
            alert("Error al Isertar los Datos");
              }
            });
            alert("Satisfactorio");
            event.target.userVar.value = "";
            event.target.passVar.value = "";
            }
        });
```

Fijate que AgregarUsuario es el nombre de tu metodo, el cual esta del lado del server

```
            Meteor.methods({
                'AgregarUsuario': function(
                  userVar,
                  passVar,
                ){
                  var idinserted=Users.insert({
                    userVar:userVar,
                    passVar:passVar
                  });
                }
            });
```